# How to bypass the initializing for a ResultSet?

Tags: java, sql, resultset

So this is part of my code :

```
            try {             
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                    ResultSet res;                  
                    res = bdd.requete(sql);
                    doSomethingWithRes()
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I would like to close the resultSet at the end of this block (to save resources), however if I add res.cose(), java will tell me that res may not have been initialized (which is true for n=0). Is there a way to initialize the resultSet without doing a query ?

I also tried

```
            try {             
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                    ResultSet res;                  
                    res = bdd.requete(sql);
                    doSomethingWithRes()
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (n>=1)
                res.close()
```

but the compiler doesn't accept it, even though it would work. Is there a way to force the compiler to accept this ?

Comment: maybe have a look at [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). This can then be used as follows: `try(ResultSet res = bdd.requete(sql)){ doSomethingWithRes();} catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}`

Answer (score 2):

You would have to increase the scope of the `ResultSet` instance; only issue is you have more than one and you should close all of them. I would suggest a `try-with-resources` like

```
try {             
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        try (ResultSet res = bdd.requete(sql)) {
            doSomethingWithRes();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```